# How to compare string variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I am trying to compare the variable using javascipt:
response value: `""test@gmail.com""`

response value i am getting it from server.

```
  var str1="test@gmail.com"
    var str2 =response;

if(str1===str2)
{
//
}
```

However not getting the proper result.
any idea on how to  compare them ?

Comment: `""test@gmail.com""` is invalid string...

Comment: `'"test@gmail.com"'.indexOf('test@gmail.com')`

Comment: @Rayon .. thanks .. yes, its an invalid string.Is there is a way we can change it?as indexOf having compatibility issues.

Comment: @RayonDabre: It's an invalid string *literal*, it's a perfectly fine string *value*. Since the OP says that the value is loaded from the server, it seems we are *not* dealing with a literal. Of course a complete example would be more useful.

Comment: @Harshit, [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Does your string value literally contain `"..."`? If so, why? You could simply remove them via `str2.replace(/"/g, '')`. Otherwise, using `===` (or less preferably `==`) is the right way of comparing strings. Please provide a better and more complete example and elaborate on what you mean by "not getting the proper result". Please read [mcve].

Comment: @FelixKling, I need a reference to understand the difference..

Comment: @RayonDabre: http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/07/26/String-Literals-vs-String-Values, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming) .

Comment: @FelixKling, Thank you! I did have the incomplete knowledge of the difference between string literals and string values ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve your goal:

**1)** You can remove all `"` from the response when doing your equality check:

```
if(str1===str2.replace(/['"]+/g, ''))
{
//
}
```

**2)** Change your server code to not include `"`.  Doing so, would mean that your Javascript will not need to change.

**3)** Last option, add `"` to your `str1`:

```
var str1='"test@gmail.com"'
var str2 =response;

if(str1===str2)
{
//
}
```

Obviously I don't know enough about your requirements to tell you which one you should do, but my suggestion would be choice `#2` because I think it's strange to return an email address wrapped in quotes, otherwise I would recommend `#1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare '""test@gmail.com""' with 'test@gmail.com'. They would never be equal.
Actually ""test@gmail.com"" is not a valid string. It might have been represented as '""test@gmail.com""' and "test@gmail.com" is a valid string (Same as 'test@gmail.com').